# CSS - Why IE6 doesn't follow this css rule li.class?

Tags: css

I am using the following rule to display a dot when the web is visited by a IE.
However, I don't know why the li.iedot doesn't work for IE6.0. In other words, all #nav-primary li displays the dot rather than #nav-primary li which has class .iedot.

```
#nav-primary li.iedot
{
    font-size:110%;
    color:#666;
    *background:url(http://static02.linkedin.com/scds/common/u/img/bg/bg_grey_dotted_h-line_3x1.png) no-repeat 0 7px;
    padding-right:2px;
    *padding-right:6px;
    *padding-left:6px;
    *zoom:1;
}

<body>
<div class="member" id="header">
 <div class="wrapper">
    <div id="nav-primary">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <ul class="nav">
                <li class="tab iedot" id="nav-primary-home">
                    <a href="#"><span>Home</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="tab iedot" id="nav-primary-profile">
                     <a href="#"><span>Profile</span></a>
             </li>
                <li class="tab" id="nav-primary-about">
                     <a href="#"><span>About</span></a>
             </li>
             </ul>

        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
</div> 
</body>
```

1> How to fix it? Or IE just cannot do it.

2> Where I can find some website that indicates which css feature is supported by IE?

Thank you

Comment: It's so hard to fight the urge to say "because it's ie6 and it's been the bane of every web developer for the last 9 years". Not helpful I know but it's a visceral reaction

Answer (score 0):

[Quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/) by ppk is the place to learn about the browser inconsistencies.

Added: why it doesn't work --

I think the IE 6 bugs with elements that have multiple classes may be tripping you up.

Test this out by changing your html to be

```
                <li class="iedot" id="nav-primary-home">
       instead of 
                <li class="tab iedot" id="nav-primary-home">
```

If that's the problem, then you'll need to use only one class name in the element. You could either invent a bunch of new class names or add a wrap div/span with the iedot class.

Comment: Why the down vote? Standard practice is to comment about what was unhelpful in the answer.

Comment: Did the downvote happen before you added the "added" bit. I would have considered downvoting if you had "go to quirksmode" without even linking to a particular page.

Comment: Hello Larry,

I don't know why someone downvoted your comments.
I have tried your proposal and it doesn't work for me.

Thank you

Comment: @Jon: yes. Hmmmm. Thank you for the feedback. I was quickly responding to the OP's question 2. (Trying to beat the masses.) I'll be more explicit about such things in the future.

Comment: @q0987: I suggest that you do some stepwise refinement: The problem is either the css selector, the css rules, or the html. Start with a simple case for all three, then add back your original content until something breaks. Eg, I'm not sure about the * css rules with IE6.

Comment: @Larry Yes, I've a habit of answering that way too.